# Handling large object in Avro Schema

Tags: object, apache-kafka, avro

Avro schemas are hit with the JVM limitation of 254 attributes while modelling an object.

If you have a Java object with 300 parameters, you cannot have this in one schema. Reason being, there cannot be a constructor with more than 254 parameters in Java.

Question:

I am not aware so let me ask:
In a Kafka-Avro set up, On the consumer part, when you read an object and de-serialize it, does Avro make use of the constructor ? or does it instantiate the object by some other means ?

If it uses the constructor, and if the producer sent an object with >254 attributes, reading will fail, it will error out, in my opinion.

Does it use the constructor? at all ? AVRO while reading the objects ?

I have not tried and I would like to know before I model my object.

Comment: Kafka doesn't use Avro on its own, so the question isn't really Kafka related... What Avro library are you using? Are you using SpecificRecord, GenericRecord, Reflection, etc? Multiple constructors are used to deserialize Avro bytes to a POJO